# Accelerometer logs events

Tags: android, accelerometer, titanium-mobile

I am working on an app that measures movement from the accelerometer, logs the data,  and recognizes a complete repition. I am using titanium mobile, currently  troubleshooting on an andriod (HTC Vivid).

For example, if you were to hold the phone in your hand, curled your arm up then reversed the motion it would log the movement as one repition.

I did 5 reps and  graphed the data:
[image: Graph]

The X axis is appears to be the only axis that can be measurable based on my needs. I am stuck on how to create an event that would trigger the app to recognize a "repition".

I don't want to use tresholds because I feel like it will provide inaccurate repitions. Can the data be filtered to provide smoother curves?
would using the gyroscope make a difference?

Comment: Yes, taking advantage of the gyroscope is a very good idea - its output is usually very precise.

Comment: For repetition detection I would consider having a look at FFT and some kind of noise/signal measure.

Comment: Upon further investigation, I saw the google talks video. Seems like I need to investigate sensor fusion to determine the orientation of the accelerometer as a starting point. Then I need to use the compass, gyro, and accelerometer to meet my criteria. I got excited when I used the moving average to filter down my results. I repeated the 1st graph, but I set the delay to 100ms and I used 2 point moving average to get this graph. The black is the AVG. This is MUCH better than the raw data. Does it look like I'm on the right path? !http://imgur.com/w7UNt

Comment: looks nice enough! Found this for the periodic motion detection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8006466/detecting-periodic-data-from-the-phones-accelerometer